# Paypal sandbox pending payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, sandbox

I want to use Paypal with Moodle to sell courses. Moodle comes with a IPN file so it's quite easy to do.

Problem comes when testing the payment process in the sandbox. Everything works fine from the user side (buying the course). Trouble comes from the seller side.

Connecting to the Paypal sandbox as a seller, I'm seeing my pending payments. I want to accept a pending payment to continue the process. That's when the problem happend. When clicking the accept button, Paypal tell me they have to verify my account and I need to add a bank account. And when I enter random numbers, Paypal just says "You cannot add a bank at this time".

So I can't accept the payment and I can't test the payment process.

Comment: Some days when I grow tired of how simple and easy my life has become, I stop using [Stripe](https://www.stripe.com/gb) and instead use Paypal. Because sometimes having headaches can be fun.

Comment: Hi @Francis, what's the merchant account ID on the seller's account?  (You can find this in the profile, on the "My business info" page.)

Answer (score 0):

So now it's working. I asked Paypal support by email 2 days ago (support@paypal-techsupport.com). Today they just made my sandbox account as "verified". Sandbox transactions are now working.

As suggested, it works well on Stripe.